# Bugs drawing with turtle(python) using onkey() and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, turtle-graphics

I decided redo this question as per advice I received, This is an assignment question I have been given for 1st year uni, python coding. I have bugs in my code and Can't figure out where to fix them.
BUG 1 The turtle starts drawing when program is ran even though pen is up.
BUG 2 undefined key such as 's, 7, tab' trigger space_bar function

COLOURING BOOK

In this task you create a children's colouring game in which
  given pictures can be coloured by tracing around a shape and
  then filling it. The controls are as follows.

ARROW KEYS - Move the "brush" (turtle cursor) left, right, up
               or down by a fixed small amount.

'z' - Undo the last step.

'r', 'g', 'b' - Change the brush colour to red, green or blue,
                  respectively.  (You can define more colours if
                  you like, but we expect at least these three.)

SPACE BAR - Toggle the painting mode.  In "move" mode, which is
              the initial mode, the "brush" (turtle) moves around
              the screen without drawing.  In "paint" mode the
              brush leaves a coloured line as it moves.  Most
              importantly, when the mode is changed from "paint"
              to "move", the area traced out by the brush is
              filled with colour.

```
from turtle import *
from functools import partial 
bgpic("Colour_A_Turkey.gif") # change this to change the picture

#control the accuracy/speed of the drawing 
step_size =8
pensize(4)
penup()

# whenever spacebar is pressed the current state  and next state switch values 
current_state = penup
next_state = pendown
def space_bar():
    global current_state, next_state
    next_state()
    current_state, next_state = next_state, current_state
    #if the current stat is penup fill in with current colour
    if current_state == penup:
        end_fill()
    else:
        begin_fill()
onkey(space_bar, " ")

# undo do a mistake function
def mistake():
    undo()
onkey(mistake, "z")

#using partial function to store the following functions
#so they can be called  as arguments from a dictionary
#movement
strait = partial(fd, step_size)
reverse = partial(bk, step_size)
turn_rt = partial(rt, step_size)
turn_lf = partial(lt, step_size)

#colour
brow = partial(color, "brown")
gree = partial(color, "green")
yell = partial(color, "yellow")
oran = partial(color, "orange")
purp = partial(color, "purple")
red = partial(color, "red")
blue = partial(color, "blue")


#create a dictionary to store all the keys and there abilities 
key_action = {"b" : blue, "r" : red, "p" : purp, "o" : oran,\
          "y" : yell, "g" : gree, "w" : brow, "Right" : turn_rt , "Up" : strait,\
          "Down" : reverse, "Left" : turn_lf, "z" : undo()}

#when a key in then above dictionary
#is pressed it's function  is activated
for pressed_key, activated_key in key_action.items():
    onkey(activated_key, pressed_key)  

#make turtle look for key strokes with predefined function
listen()
#finish
done()
```

Comment: what do functions fd,bk,undo,rt,lt return you ?

Comment: forward(x)/back(x)/undo last thing turtle did/right(x)/left(x). all predefined functions that come with turtle

Comment: IS fixed now thanks everyone who helped, I defined z only once and changed " " to "space"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, in Python, *everything is an object and we really mean that*. Functions are objects too. We can store functions in a dictionary, and in fact that's exactly what you seem to want to do here.

```
turn_lf = lt(step_size )
```

The key problem here is that you want to store "a function that calls `lt` with `step_size` as the argument", but here you have just called `lt` with `step_size` as an argument immediately, and stored the return value.

Arguably the simplest way to get what you want is to use `functools.partial` to "bind" the `step_size` argument.

```
from functools import partial
turn_lf = partial(lt, step_size) # `lt` is not called yet.

# Now, later on, we can do
turn_lf() # and it's just as if we did `lt(step_size)`.
# So now we can store `turn_lf` in a dict, look it up and call it later, etc.

# Similarly for all the other functions you want to make.
```

(Another problem is that you haven't been consistent with this; if you want everything to go in one dict, then you need to indicate the bindings for the `color` function as well. `'brown'` is just a string, after all. Fortunately, this is just as simple as with the other functions: we just make our `partial(color, 'brown')`.

As for `"z" : delete`, well - we don't have any arguments to bind to `undo`. So while we *could* follow the pattern and write `partial(undo)` (notice, no more arguments, because we aren't binding anything), it makes much more sense to just write `undo` directly.

As an aside, we can simplify this:

```
for key in key_action:
    pressed_key = key
    activated_key = key_action[key]
```

To this:

```
for pressed_key, activated_key in key_action.items():
```

Comment: no module called fuctools..sorry I'm new to coding, never done it before this unit, I have to use python 2.7 for marking reasons where would i find this fuctools module

Answer (score -1):

Why define all the functions? We can directly use:
Break the dict as :

```
key_action = {"b" : "blue", "r" : "red", "p" : "purple", "o" : "orange", "y" : "yellow","g" : "green", "w" : "brown","Right" : rt , "Left": lt, "Up" : fd, "Down" : bk,"z" : undo}


no_input = ["z"]

one_input = ["Right", "Left", "Up", "Down"]

for key in key_action:
    activated_key = key_action[key]
    if key in no_input:
       activated_key()
    elif key in one_input():
        activated_key(step_size)
    else:
        onkey(color(activated_key), key)
```

Comment: got an errorif len(color) == 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: gahh i entered instead of shift enter sorry for double post
if len(color) == 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
also I want to be able to control the turtle with the arrow keys and undo() with z  and change color all with this function.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have a look at it. It is similar to the next answer answered in your question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all the keys, including things like `'z'`, need to be bound with `onkey` the same way that the colour-changing keys are. The point of this loop is not to handle input directly, but to set up key bindings that will let the turtle-graphics framework know how to handle input.

Answer (score -1):

Your dictionary approach is along the right way of thinking. However, your function will not behave correctly. Using a dictionary is simplier than you think. First of all you have to have separate *FUNCTIONS* against *STRING* and handle them correctly. As each of them will behave differently:

```
# Get rid of the top four lines, they will not work
# All actions mapping
key_action = {"b" : "blue", "r" : "red", "p" : "purple", "o" : "orange",
              "y" : "yellow", "g" : "green", "w" : "brown",
              "Right" : rt , "Left": lt, "Up" : fd, "Down" : bk,
              "z" : undo}
# Note down which are special actions
# Functions with no input
foo = ["z"]
# Function with one input
bar = ["Right", "Left", "Up", "Down"]

# Assuming the input key is get here, I don't use turtle don't know how
# the input is read
key = listen()  # PSEUDOCODE!

# Handle the input
if key in foo:
     foo[key]() # Execute no input function
elif key in bar:
     foo[key](step_size)
else:
     onkey(key_action[key], key)
```